# how to save checked checkboxes after reloading data using ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, django

I defined a dropbox selector which after selecting a country gives me a list of cities as checkboxs. I am using jquery and ajax to preview it and select it as follow.

```
<div>
    <div id="preview-items">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
     $("#id_country").change(function () {
          var countryId = $(this).val();  // get the selected country ID from the HTML input

          $.ajax({  // initialize an AJAX request
            url: '/ajax/ajax_load_cities',
            data: {
                 'countries': countryId   // add the country id to the GET parameters
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) { // `data` is the return of the `load_cities` view function
             $('#preview-items').html('');
    
             for (var i in data.tags) {
                   $('#preview-items').append(`
                       <label class="btn btn-primary mr-1"> 
                       <input type="checkbox"  id="checklist_` + data.tags[i][0]+ `" value="` + data.tags[i][0] + `"> 
                       <span> 
                         ` + data.tags[i][1] + ` 
                       </span> 
                       </label><br />` 
                    ).find("#checklist_" + data.tags[i][0]).on("change", function(e){

                    var cities_array = $(":checkbox:checked").map( function() { return $(this).next().html(); }).get();
                    $("#preview-items").html(cities_array.join(', '));

                   if (e.target.checked) { 
                       localStorage.checked = true;
                    } else {
                        localStorage.checked = false; 
                    } 

              }
            }
           });
      });
</script>
```

and in django `view.py`:

```
def load_cities(request):
    ....
    
    data = {
        'tags': list(cities)
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

The problem is that, it does not keep the selected cities after changing the country selectors. after googling, I found that cookies are a good choice. I wanted to know how to save selected checkboxes when dropbox items change?

Comment: the first script does not make sense and it does not even look like a valid javascript. What's the `success` function doing there?

Comment: updated my question, however  in `Success`  function: `data` is the return of the `load_cities` view function. It returns a dictionary with a list of lists

Comment: no it does not. Maybe if it would be a part of `$.ajax()` or something like that. But not like this.

Comment: Your server side call seems a bit strange. So your goal is to show a list of cities with checkboxes, and whenever a city is selected you want to send that to the server, right? If so, I suggest the response from the server always is a list of cities with the selected property in it. Such as `[{name: "Amsterdam", checked: true}]`. Is that an option? If so I will create a proper answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really need cookies or localstorage. I suggest you take another approach:

- first you create the javascript code that builds the dropbox selector based on a state, in your example the list of cities.
- then when you make the ajax call you just call that function again.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var $container = $('#preview-items')  

  // when starting or loading the page I suggest either outputting the initial list
  // of unchecked data in your markup somewhere as a json object
  // or perform an initial ajax call. Here I just store it in a local variable.
  var initialData = [
    {id: 1, name: "Amsterdam", checked: false},
    {id: 2, name: "Berlin", checked: true},
    {id: 3, name: "Brussels", checked: false},
  ]
  
  buildDropbox(initialData)
  
  function buildDropbox(cities) {
    $container.empty()
    cities.forEach(function(city) {
      let checked = city.checked? "checked=\"checked\"" : ""
      $container.append(`
                       <label class="btn btn-primary mr-1" for="checklist_${city.id}"> 
                       <input type="checkbox" ${checked} id="checklist_${city.id}" value="${city.id}"> 
                       <span>${city.name}</span> 
                       </label><br />` 
      )
      var chk = document.getElementById("checklist_" + city.id)
      chk.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
        saveChange(e.currentTarget.name, e.currentTarget.value, e.currentTarget.checked)
      })
    }) 
  }
  
  function saveChange(chkName, chkValue, chkChecked) {
    console.log("POST ajax for " + chkValue + " with checked: " + chkChecked);
    // do your ajax call here, and in the success
    // be sure to return the same list as the
    // initialData, but with the updated 'checked'
    // value, obviously.
    // here, for testing purposes, I reuse the initialData
    // and check all checkboxes randomly
    let updatedData = initialData.map(function(c) {
      return {...c, checked: Math.round(Math.random()) == 0}
    })
    buildDropbox(updatedData)
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  
  <div id="preview-items"></div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example. It may not work here due to restrictions, but you can set it up to work for you.

It saves every 5 seconds and checks if its true, and if it is, save it.

```js
var check = document.getElementById("checkbox1");

function change() {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    change();
    if (check.checked == true) {
      localStorage.setItem("isChecked", check.checked);
    }
  }, 5000);
}
change();

window.onload = function() {
  check.checked = localStorage.getItem("isChecked")
}
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<h1>Click the check box</h1>
<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"> <!--Your Checkbox-->
```

I hope it works for your app!